# get attribute names of class python/ get column names of query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to have the column names of my sqlalchemy query
but I do not find how I can do this.

I tried a few ways

first way I have tried was to make a new class,  because the names had to be different of the column names

```
class DosierWeergave():
    def __init__(self, code_arg, year_registr, period_registr, staynum, status):
        self.Code_Arg = str(code_arg)
        self.Year_registr = str(year_registr)
        self.Period_registr = str(period_registr)
        self.Staynum = str(staynum)
        self.Status = str(status)
```

And then I maked an object of this

```
a = DosierWeergave(187,2010,4,"0000010000", "inbehandeling")
```

I get then the right names but not in the right order.
Does anybody know how I can get the columnnames (class attributes) in the right order.

Another way was to use the function: columns.keys()

```
HeaderDosiers = Dosiers2.__table__.columns.keys()
```

but her I got all the column headers and I do not find how I can filter them
has anybody an idea how I can fix this problems or has anybody got a better way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do with the column names; if you want to print them, create a **str** function:

```
def __str__(self):
    str  = 'Code Arg', self._code_arg
    str += 'Year_registr', self.Year_registr
    ...

    return str
```

I would not suggest using reflection.

Comment: I want to use them for my column headers in my pyramid project
and I am using therefor ZPT.tal:repeat